# Move online first react native app to offline first with mongodb realm

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, realm-migration

I am having challenges migrating my online app (node backend) to be offline first.
I have successfully connected my app to the app services and enable device sync.
In the users section under app services, i have registered users and am able to log them in  in my app.
However here is where am stuck, I want to link the user to their data which they had while the app was online.
What do I mean?
While the app was online they would login through a rest api endpoint, right ? and as per the schema each user would their data.
In mongo realm I did not find a way to login the user with the data that is already stored in mongo db. The only way was to create users under the user section in app services.(please correct me if am wrong here)
This works and i can log them in, but now i want to access the data in mongo db so i can display that to the users.
How can achieve this?
please any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Authenticating users in Realm is covered in the Realm React Native SDK Documentation [Authenticate Users](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/authenticate-users/). Reading data is done using realm/react hooks for objects defined in your projects code [Read Data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/crud/read/). Lastly, applications that use Device Sync define their schema on the backend using 
[JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html). Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Thanks for replying
1.Is there a way I can use the user data already in my user collection to authenticate my users via realm? (I did not find anything about it on the docs, so i went ahead and registered new users via the realm interface and set up the logic to login them in to my app that works fine )
2. If I cannot use the user data already in atlas, and I go ahead register new user via the realm interface, is there a way I can link the data in my collection to the new user I just created?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the question; a *user collection* is unrelated to authentication. While other user data may exist in a collection it will not impact actual authentication. That's handled by the app services authentication section in the console e.g. if a user is created they can authenticate through any of the SDK's and other services. As far as existing data goes, as shown in the docs, if the object models are defined in code match the object models in Atlas, they will sync. In other words, the object models have to exist within the code so the server knows what to push to the app.

Comment: Okay, so assume you had an app that used  Rest apis to authenticate users and fetch their data and normal crud operations, and now you decide to add offline functionality, how would you go about it with realm?. consider users already signed up. would you ask them to sign up again by implementing the authentication methods offered by realm?

Comment: The question is kinda 'big' but in a nutshell; if a user exists in Atlas (e.g. you can see them in MongoDB Console->App Services->Your App->App Users) then they can authenticate using any SDK as it's the same user. Likewise, if I have data in Atlas that I want to sync locally, I would create a Realm project and within that project define Realm Objects that match the objects stored in Atlas. Those objects (data) would then Sync from Atlas to local storage.

Comment: Nice, so my issue is I have a collection in atlas holding my current users AUTH information. but i cant seem to find a way to link that up to/ access via App (Services->Your App->App Users) am using the reactnative sdk.

Comment: Hmm. There is no AUTH data stored in a collection, so ?? Perhaps you're also storing [Customer User Info](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/custom-user-data/)? As far as auth'ing a user, if they are visible in App Users, *Realm provides an API for auth'ing users using any enabled auth provider* and is covered here [Configure User Auth](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/authenticate-users/#configure-user-authentication-in-client) and [Log In](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/authenticate-users/#log-in)

Comment: I feel like you have not gotten what am trying to achieve. Currently users can log in to my app using a rest api endpoint (like every other app out there),This info to verify them is the one they fed while registering and it is stored in my collection in atlas. In realm to log in they must be visible in App Users (as you have said).Since its my first time using realm my App users is empty. As you can see the is a gap here

Comment: Yep but I am trying! The issue is here - **This info to verify them is the one they fed while registering and it is stored in my collection in atlas**.  A collection would not be involved with auth'ing; User auth data is stored with their user object at (Services->Your App->App Users) and does not directly involve storing user data in a collection. See [User Data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/users/read-metadata/#std-label-user-objects). You may be storing custom_data but that's not involved with auth'ing a user. Users can auth from any SDK with a username & pw (for example)